# How can I predict logistic model?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, logistic, mathematical-statistics

The data is like this.(of course, I have a more data)

```
week  name reponse x1      x2
 5    a      1    1.9    0.5
 6    a      1    1.4    0.4      
 7    a      1    1.62   0.2     
 8    a      1    1.2    0.1
 4    b      0    1      0.2
 5    b      0    1.3    0.3
 7    b      0    1.4    0.4
 8    b      0    0.95   0.3
 1    c      1   -0.6    0.2
 8    c      1    0.2    0.1
```

I want to know whether whose response is 1 or 0.

```
model <- glm(response ~ week + x1 + x2, data = df)
predict(model, new_data, type = "response")
```

but the output is

```
  1         2         3         4         5 
0.3266134 0.3967968 0.4260996 0.4576125 0.5436105 
        6         7         8         9        10 
0.5428340 0.5596906 0.6288423 0.7670795 0.4516189
```

I want to print the `"a" is (predictions) "b" is (predictions), ... etc`, not `1 is  0.3266134, 2 is 0.3967968 .. etc.`

How can I fix it?

If the code is right, how can I interpret it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code ignores the binary nature of the response, and the fact that you have multiple observations with the same `name`. Without knowing details of the variables and the data collection, it is impossible to be sure what is the appropriate model to use.

But assuming `name` refers to the subjects, and you are measuring the same subjects in different weeks, this is longitudinal data, and you should probably use a mixed effects model.

For example,

```
library(lme4)
model <- glmer(response ~ week + x1 + x2 + (1 | name), 
             family=binomial, data=df)
```

The `family=binomial` indicates that `response` is a binary variable. The `(1 | name)` indicates that the data are repeated measures on the same subjects. The model has a random effect for subjects.

Now to answer your question, it depends what you mean by a prediction. You have different values of the covariates `x1` and `x2` for each week/subject combination, so you naturally have a different prediction for each row of your data. Just use `predict()` to get these values. The order of the resulting output is the same as the order of the rows in your data frame.

If you are expecting one value per `name`, then I assume you want to estimate effects due to the subject rather than predictions. You can get that with `ranef(model)`. However, these will be conditional on the `week`, `x1` and `x2` being zero. You can estimate subject effects conditional on other values of `week`, `x1` and `x2`; a common approach is to set them to their median values.

Comment: I'm sorry. My purpose is to predict name's response(i.e, state) on week9, week 10, ... etc.

Comment: What kind of analysis I do for it?

Comment: Just use `predict` in that case. The order of the results is the same as the order of your rows.